# Is there any combination of 'WHERE' 'like' and 'OR' in sqlite?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

a is value entered by user.

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column-name LIKE ?', ('%{}%'.format(a,))
```

The database must show value matching with entered value. It shows for one column only. I want to retrieve record for more than one column. Need to use OR operator but not sure the syntax. Could anyone plz help me.

Comment: Please read the tag info of sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Just expand the `where`  clause with more conditions, separated by `OR` - accordingly, you need to repeat the bind parameters:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE ? OR col2 LIKE ?', ('%{}%'.format(a, a))
```

Comment: i tried doing the same, but it gives an error , 'Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.'